# Newline in Multicolumn Breaking Document

Tags: line-breaking, texmaker, multicolumn

If I try to add newlines by inserting the characters '\\' into the multicolumn it breaks the entire document. Is there any simple way to bypass this?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{2.5cm} | p{4.5cm} | p{4cm} | p{3cm} | } 
\hline
Filename & File Location & MD5 Hash & Time Last Modified \\ 
\hline
\hline
sdfsdfsdf & fsdfsdf & de6a6b6319c edf4e91bc2065faf0 & 02/12/2008 \newline 14:57 \\

\hline
\multicolumn{4}{| p{14cm}| }{

Here are the numbers. This is a long text that may splits on several lines.

48053-5555-1234-5566 Zd10/19
48587.2545.5456.5555 FH96/29
44544 5588 5124 2458 5607/38

58872 8787 8787 4547 1078/38
55981-1574-6644-5567 691x/09
58743-2645-5684-4564 7D85/58
}\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You can help us to help you by providing the code for a small **compilable document** that shows your problem called [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). Just edit your question and add missing code.

Comment: The tabular thinks the \\ is ending the row, not the sentence.  \newline or \par should work (not tested).

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

Inside a tabular `\\` has the meaning of "end the current tabular row" and not its default meaning in text "make a new line".

You can instead use its long form which is `\newline`.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, turned out I could add newlines by just doubling the amount of line breaks like so:

Visa

```
4805-5555-1234-5566 Exp 10/09

4858.2545.5456.5555 Exp 6/09

4454 5588 5124 2458 Exp 07/08

Mastercard

5887 8787 8787 4547 Exp 10/08

5598-1574-6644-5567 Exp 6/09

5874-2645-5684-4564 Exp 5/08
```

Comment: Please, a valid answer should have a **compilable** code for a fast proof ...

Comment: this is not making a new line it is ending the current paragraph and starting a new one (might look similar but isn't always.